# mysqli_row_nums didn't work when query was given

Tags: php, database, oop, mysqli, connection

I am creating a login page using PHP and Mysqli database, I wrote the query, however mysqli_num_rows() give me an error when value is given. PS: I did this in Object Oriented Format

```
<?php



$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = ""; 
$db = "customerdb"; 


$connection = @new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);   
if ($connection->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection failed!");
    exit();
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $script = "SELECT * FROM customer_management WHERE 
    customer_management.Username='".$username."'AND WHERE customer_management_Password='".$password."'";
    $result = $connection->query($script, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    $check = $result->num_rows; 




    if ($check >= 1){
        echo "Welcome to this website";

        } 

    else{

        echo"Sorry but your input is incorrect!";

    }


}

?>

<!DCOTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<input type="text" placeholder = 'username' name="username" /><br /><br />
<input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sidenote: this is incorrect `<!DCOTYPE html>` if that's your real code.

Comment: You have multiple WHERE clauses in your query. Remove the second one.

Comment: having checked for errors on this........ oh never mind.  Just RTM will ya? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html and don't use plain text passwords; you'll get done in for sure.

Comment: Why the ampersand before `@new`?

Comment: @Marcus they're suppressing possible errors.

Comment: Lol. I know. Was hoping to hear reasoning from OP. Shouldn't be suppressing errors in dev

Comment: do yourself a favor http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @fred-ii- you seem like a real awesome guy.

Comment: (For reference) From a [user contribution note](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289): _"you have to declare ->store_result() first"_

Comment: Hi guys, I changed my html tag to <!DOCTYPE html> and I got rid of the second WHERE clauses.  I still get the same error  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 24.

Answer (score 0):

Change `customer_management_Password` to `customer_management.Password` in your query.

Comment: Hold on here cowboy.. `customer_management_Password` how do you that isn't their column name?

Comment: It is an assumption, which I feel to be an educated one.

Comment: any which way; you missed something **crucial**

Comment: still didn't spot it huh?